# Error loading a TF lite format model in ios device for custom object detection

Tags: ios, object, tensorflow, detection

I have trained a custom object detection, using transfer learning based on MobileNetV2. I converted the model to tflite format so that I can run it on my IOS device. However, when I run the model in xcode, I get an error.

```
2019-08-20 16:11:07.225613+0100 ObjectDetection[5692:1119136] 
Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
2019-08-20 16:11:07.280287+0100 ObjectDetection[5692:1119136] [MC] 
System group container for 
systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is 
/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configu    
rationprofiles
2019-08-20 16:11:07.282075+0100 ObjectDetection[5692:1119136] [MC] 
Reading from public effective user settings.

**Failed to invoke the interpreter with error: Provided data count 
1080000 must match the required count 602112.
Failed to invoke the interpreter with error: Provided data count 
1080000  must match the required count 602112.**
```